# Create repository action from form selected items in Symfony2?

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

**EDIT I found how to get data**

```
    $filter_form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($filter_form->isValid()) {
        $users = $filter_form->get('users')->getViewData();
        $tags = $filter_form->get('tags')->getData();

        $links = $em->getRepository('LanCrmBundle:Link')->findFiltered($users, $tags);
    } else {
        $links = $em->getRepository('LanCrmBundle:Link')->findBy(
            array(),
            array('id' => 'desc')
        );
    }
```

Now I have to create findFiltered method in my repository.

But I don't know how to make it working.

```
public function findFiltered($users, $tags)
{
    $queryBuilder = $this->createQueryBuilder('l');

    $queryBuilder->orderBy('l.id', 'desc');

    if($users) {
        ???
    }

    if($tags) {
        ???
    }

    return $queryBuilder->getQuery()->getResult();

}
```

I hope I was understandable, if not do not hesitate to ask me more information.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What is the relation between *Link* and *users*, *tags*?

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specify the associations types but it should be something like:

```
return $this->_em
    ->createQuery(
        'SELECT l FROM LanCrmBundle:Link '.
        'WHERE l.user IN (:users) AND l.tag IN (:tags) '.
        'ORDER BY l.id DESC')
    ->setParameter('users', $users)
    ->setParameter('tags', $tags)
    ->getResult();
```

Comment: I've added `->_em` please try again